# Sort rows in a matrix with a vector

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Let's suppose I have a matrix:

$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i
\end{array}\right]$

and I want to sort the rows using a sort-vector:

$sortVec=\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
3\\
2
\end{array}\right]$

This would mean that my second row in matrix A would need to be placed at row number 3 and the thrid row would need to be placed at row number 2.

Outcome:

$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
g & h & i\\
d & e & f
\end{array}\right]$

How can I do it in Mathematica?

my question aims at a simple solution.
As far as I can see, it is not a duplicate of "Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns".

Comment: `a = Partition[Alphabet[][[;; 9]], 3];
a[[{1, 3, 2}]]`

Comment: just `A[[sortVec]]`

Comment: @march This is not a duplicate of the one you reference, as sorting is not listed among those operations. However...

Comment: @IstvánZachar. I somewhat agree with your assessment, although I would say that the OP used the wrong word in "sort", because really this is just rearranging the rows of the matrix, which is a generalization of "swapping two rows". However, either one is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for a permutation, so use [`Permute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute.html)

```
m = Partition[Symbol /@ CharacterRange["a", "i"], 3]
```

> `{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}`

```
Permute[m, {1, 3, 2}]
```

> `{{a, b, c}, {g, h, i}, {d, e, f}}`