# General way to permute rows in a matrix (tensor)

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, permutation

I have a matrix:

$m=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & d\\
e & f & g & h\\
i & j & k & l\\
m & n & o & p\\
q & r & s & t\\
u & v & w & x
\end{bmatrix}$

and I want to sort the rows of the matrix using a sort list:

$sortVec=\left\{ \left\{ 2,1,3\},\{3,1,2\}\right\} \right\}$

so that the output is:

$m=\begin{bmatrix}
e & f & g & h\\
a & b & c & d\\
i & j & k & l\\
q & r & s & t\\
u & v & w & x\\
m & n & o & p
\end{bmatrix}$

The problem is that when I want to use something like:

```
Permute[data, sortVec]
```

then sortVec would need to be

```
sortVec={2,1,3,6,5,4}
```

but I don't want to type out the entire vector, but rather permute parts of the matrix...

Comment: Your second matrix doesn't match up with your $sortVec$.  If it did, then this would work:  `m[[Catenate[sortVec + 3 Range[0, Length@sortVec - 1]]]]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort rows in a matrix with a vector](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123504/sort-rows-in-a-matrix-with-a-vector)

Comment: @JasonB, please look at my edit.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
m = Partition[Alphabet[], 4];

sortVec = {{2, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 2}};

Permute[m, Join @@ FoldList[Max[#] + #2 &, sortVec]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \text{e} & \text{f} & \text{g} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{i} & \text{j} & \text{k} & \text{l} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{r} & \text{s} & \text{t} \\
>  \text{u} & \text{v} & \text{w} & \text{x} \\
>  \text{m} & \text{n} & \text{o} & \text{p} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

It also works with mixed cycle lengths:

```
{{2, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {1}};

Join @@ FoldList[Max[#] + #2 &, %]

Permute[m, %]
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 5, 3, 4, 6}
> ```
>
> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \text{e} & \text{f} & \text{g} & \text{h} \\
>  \text{a} & \text{b} & \text{c} & \text{d} \\
>  \text{m} & \text{n} & \text{o} & \text{p} \\
>  \text{q} & \text{r} & \text{s} & \text{t} \\
>  \text{i} & \text{j} & \text{k} & \text{l} \\
>  \text{u} & \text{v} & \text{w} & \text{x} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Wizard  Great ! Thank you very much!

Comment: @DoHe You're welcome.  However I see a possible problem; is your `sortVec` always composed of lists of the same length, or could you have something like `sortVec = {{2, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {1}}`?  If the latter we will need something more general.

Comment: hmm you are right, it would probably need something more general.

Comment: @DoHe Please see the update.

Comment: Wizard: Great work !! Thank you!

Comment: @DoHe Glad I could help. :-)